# Android second activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am using Android studio 2.2 IM place code from Android we rocks, but Android studio output APK which is note launch in next activity unfortunately closed. Someone can you tell me a perfect Java code for launch second activity?

Comment: Welcome to `SO`.please post your code and error along with question..

Answer (score 0):

You answer is by using an intent. Also make sure both your activities are registered in manifest.

```
Intent intent_to_ActivityB = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent_to_ActivityB);
```